# Cannot read property when this property is exist

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I getting data from mongodb via mongoose. Then I try pass data to jade via res.render, but always get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null`, but this property is exist and valid.

The code:

```
router.get('/item/:sku', (req, res, next) => {
  Item.getItem(req.params.sku, (err, data) => {
    console.log(data)
    if(err)
      next(err)
    res.render('item', {
      title: data.name,
      data: data
    })
  })
})
```

Output:

```
{ sale: false,
  createdAt: Fri Apr 29 2016 01:11:48 GMT+0700 (KRAT),
  ordered: 0,
  views: 0,
  tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4' ],
  images: [ 'squirrel.jpg' ],
  __v: 0,
  backImage: '',
  category: 57223f8ac80eb66928eae23e,
  sku: 'SCH-002',
  salePrice: 0,
  price: 250,
  description: 'test description',
  name: 'Squirrel',
  _id: 57225264b83ae185f3b2f4dc }
GET /item/SCH-002 200 1398.341 ms - 19177
/Users/lee/Projects/shepki/routes/index.js:30
      title: data.name,
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
at /Users/lee/Projects/shepki/routes/index.js:30:18
at /Users/lee/Projects/shepki/modules/item.js:55:5
```

But if remove title and pass just whole data - its OK. I don't understand what's wrong.
Thanks.